# Proceeding Row Header to the next row in DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#

How to proceed row header to the next row? This is my code.

```
dgNames.Rows[dgNames.CurrentRow.Index].Selected = false;
dgNames.Rows[dgNames.CurrentRow.Index + 1].Selected = true;
```

It only proceed and highlight the next row. But the row header is still on the previous row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the currentRow to the new row like this:

```
  dgNames.Rows[dgNames.CurrentRow.Index].Selected = false;
  dgNames.Rows[dgNames.CurrentRow.Index + 1].Selected = true;
  dgNames.CurrentCell = dgNames[0, dgNames.CurrentRow.Index + 1];
```

The trick is to set the CurrentCell as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The header row is always the first row (index 0) in a DataGridView.